# JTable заполнение данными из БД

Tags: java, mysql

Может есть где статейка, где расписано все по полочкам, как обращаться с JTable, моделью, как заполнить JTable данными из бд, а то перерыл весь гугл, ничего толкового не нашел) "How to Use Tables" не предлагать)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А что же никак нельзя разделить задачу на 2 части?

1. Прочитать данные из MySQL - [фтыкаем тут](http://zetcode.com/databases/mysqljavatutorial/)
2. Заполнить данными `JTable` - [смотрим сюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9447903/store-arraylist-data-in-a-jtable)